# JLabel not displaying

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I am trying to add a linebreak in a JLabel. '\n' does not work and I have found that using HTML should be a solution, but whenever I try anything with HTML it causes my JFrame to disappear or not be visible anymore. I am using NetBeans 8.2 and Java JDK  1.8.0_251. Is there any solution to this? Thank you

```
 WindowMain = new JFrame("Spasitel");
   WindowMain.setSize(960, 720);
   WindowMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   WindowMain.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   //WindowMain.getContentPane().setFont(Courier New);
   WindowMain.setLayout(null);
   WindowMain.setResizable(false);
   WindowMain.setVisible(true);
   Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
   WindowMain.setLocation(size.width/2 - WindowMain.getWidth()/2, size.height/2 - WindowMain.getHeight()/2);

   JPanel TitleFrame = new JPanel();
   TitleFrame.setBounds(50,50, 860, 200);
   TitleFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   JLabel TitleText = new JLabel ("<html>Hello World!<br/>blahblahblah</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
   //TitleText.setFont("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 18);
   TitleFrame.add(TitleText);
   TitleFrame.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
   TitleFrame.show();
   TitleFrame.setVisible(true);
   WindowMain.add(TitleFrame);
```

[With HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sKQd.png)

[Without HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhwOw.png)

Comment: Try `<html><body>Hello World!<br>blahblahblah</body></html>`

Comment: @MatthewKerian I edited the post to show you what happened. I tired using <body></body> and it still doesnt work for me. Could I be missing a piece of code to display JLabel HTML text in a JFrame?

Comment: You need to post your [mre] code with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following GUI.

[image: JLabel Example]

I used a `JFrame`, a `JPanel`, and a `JLabel`.  I called the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method to start the Swing GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread,

I used Swing layout managers.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabelExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JLabelExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        String s = "<html>This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.  ";
        s += "<br />This is only a test.";
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much. seems to be working now adapted to your code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use html tags with a null layout, try setting a layout.

Eg:

```
WindowMain.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```